# Real-time localization with vision only SLAM

Tags: slam, navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am working on the implementation in an embedded system of a vision only SLAM algorithm. I have then to pick an algorithm ensuring efficiency and precison. I read about algorithms (EKF SLAM, FASTSLAM, GraphSLAM..) and i found that the literature contains so many approaches..For the EKF version, I found the approach of Davidson implementating a real-time EKF vision only SLAM..I wanna ask if there are approaches of graphslam or fastslam using only cameras (no odometry) and ensuring a real-time localization of a robot?
Thank you for your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/136251/real-time-localization-with-vision-only-slam/) by [Lamiss](https://answers.ros.org/users/12871/lamiss/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2014-03-06

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you are looking at vision-only, you could look at ethzasl_ptam. If you need the odometry in real world coordinates, you need to EKF with an IMU. If you dont want to use an IMU, you can try stereo based slam such as ScaviSLAM. Both are pose graph slam approaches

---

Originally posted by [aswin](https://answers.ros.org/users/212/aswin/) with karma: 528 on 2014-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0